# What kind of 8GB RAM Stick works with the Lenovo S210 Touch?

Tags: laptop, memory

I would like to upgrade my [Lenovo S210 Touch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00F32ZB68) from 4 to 8GB of RAM. I never did this before and I'm not sure what kind of RAM I need to buy. I think it needs to be a 8GB stick of DDR3L-SDRAM.

Overview:

```
Model: Lenovo S210 Touch
Processor: Intel Pentium Processor Dual-Core 987 1.5 GHz w/ Intel HD Graphics
Chipset: Intel HM76 Express
Memory: 4GB PC3-10600 1333MHz DDR3L
Max Memory Supported: 8GB
Storage: 500GB SSHDD 2.5" SATA 6Gb/s 5400RPM
```

What RAM stick works with my device?

Answer (score 5):

Referring to a [manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad_s210s210touchs215_hmm.pdf) of your notebook there is one RAM slot (DDR3L 1333/1600) in your device, which can support up to 8GB of memory:

[image: Lenovo S210 Touch manual]

But after checking memory modules compatible with your CPU ([ARK site](http://ark.intel.com/products/67194/Intel-Pentium-Processor-987-2M-Cache-1_50-GHz)) it says that maximum supported frequency of memory for your CPU is 1333 MHz:

[image: CPU specification]

Therfore, I would recommend replacing your 4GB RAM module with a

- G.SKILL (F3-1333C9S-8GSL) - DDR3L, 8GB, 1333 MHz, CL9 - [$33.99 at newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231693)

Comment: Be sure that the RAM inside of this laptop is not soldered. Desoldering RAM is nearly impossible without the right tools and expertise. If the ram is indeed soldered, than it would be pointless to attempt to replace it.